# Do calling one web api method by more users will slow down the server?

Tags: performance, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, c#-5.0

Do calling one web api method by more users will slow down the server ?
I have  two functionality. And I can easily combine it into one using a single parameter. I have a doubt that whether it will slow down when we join the method thus the number of calls to one web api method will be more. Please help on this.

Am asking about same web server and comparing the performance between these two scenarios.

```
**Case 1:**

commonapi(string param)
{
  if(param)
    do x;
  else 
    do y
 }

**Case 2:**
    api1()
     {
      do x;
     }

    api2()
     {
      do y;
      }
```

Which case have more performance as in case 1, single api method is being called for both the functionalities. And in case 2, separate calls have been done. So traffic to method will be halved. Any difference

Comment: Doesn't matter, I would consider if those two are different actions I will go with two methods but still internally have one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Do calling one web api method by more users will slow down the server?

Yes

The more simultaneous calls to the server the slower it will get, by how much and to what extent is an unknown. Build your system cleanly with one eye on speed then once it's built load test it and optimize based on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Just like any web service or website, excessive requests (among many other factors) can impact performance because you are making a request to the server unless you take the necessary steps to set up a solid architectural design and an efficient Web API service.